# Sticky Footer in Bootstrap 2.3.2 causing huge gap and scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have implemented this [sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html) for Bootstrap 2.3.2 on my site but am running into an issue on a page that has short content [here](http://www.themightymouth.org/how-to-do-it/flossing/).  There is too much space between the content and the footer, as well as an inconvenient scrollbar.  Is there a way to prevent the huge gap in space and the scroll bar on a short page with short content?

I am using this code to generate the sticky footer.

```
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
}

#wrap{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -150px;
}

#push{
    height: 150px;
}

#footer{
   background-color: #3BC1CD;
   height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/BfJn6L0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Bootstrap example, simply move your `#push` div **in** the `#wrap` div :

```
<div id="wrap">
    ...
    <div id="push"></div>
</div><!-- #wrap -->
<div id="footer">
    ...
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not giving the desired result because the `#push div` is outside of the `wrapper div`.

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have :

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

in bootstrap they have :

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Just indent the #push inside the #wrap

Comment: Whoops!  Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. That fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Remove the height on `<div id="push">` or remove it altogether. This is unnecessary.

Comment: Or just remove `<div id="push">` completely, not sure why you have it there in the first place.

Comment: when I remove the #push div the content on the long pages runs into the footer.  Also, I believe the negative margin on the #wrap is supposed to be the same height as the footer (my footer is 150px).

Comment: I see. Why is there a `margin-top: 70px;` on `footer` in `custom.css`? Can you remove that then?